# Cannot launch Nautilus due to libunity.so.6 missing

Tags: libunity

When I try to launch nautilus i got this error:

> nautilus: error while loading shared libraries: libunity.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I got the same with Marlin & Brasero.

I have tried this command:

> sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libunity.so.9 /usr/lib/libunity.so.6

but it doesn't work at all.

Im going to cry... Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

Are you on Oneiric? You could try

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libunity6
```

How to obtain this answer?

I first used

```
ldd /usr/bin/nautilus | grep unity
```

to check that it indeed needs `libunity.so.6` on my machine as well. Then i ran

```
dpkg -S /usr/lib/libunity.so.6
```

to find out what package contains that file. It turns out that the package is `libunity6`. So it makes sense to try to reinstall it, which is what the above command does.

Comment: I got this error:

Reinstallation of libunity6 is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.

What should I do now?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get update` and then try again. If that does not help: try going to the software centre, edit -> software sources, and select 'download from: main server'. then `sudo apt-get update` and try again.

Comment: when I ran: 
dpkg -S /usr/lib/libunity.so.6

I got this:
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/lib/libunity.so.6.